# Error `not assingable` with setting `fontWeight` in `makeStyles` using `theme` Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, docker, material-ui, next.js

I am using a NextJS project together with `MUI` and I am trying to set a `fontWeight` property using my `theme` settings within the `makeStyles` function. The errors only occurs when building inside a docker container. Building locally works fine.

```js
export const useTableStyles = makeStyles(theme =>
    createStyles({
        spannedTableCell: {
            fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightBold
        }
    })
);
```

However when my docker container is building I got the following error:
[image]

I'm using node v16.13.0 both in the container and locally

Container (`node:lts-alpine3.12`):

[image]

Local:

[image]

This is the `typography` theme settigs:

```js
typography: {
    fontFamily: '"Roboto", serif',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeightLight: 300,
    fontWeightRegular: 400,
    fontWeightMedium: 500,
    fontWeightBold: 700,
    htmlFontSize: 16
},
```

MUI versions I use

```
"@material-ui/core": "^4.12.2",
"@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
"@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.60",
"@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
```

**EDIT:**
I changed the values hardcoded to `bold`, `normal` etc and now it works fine

Comment: This is mostly likely caused by different versions of some packages. Could you post your `package.json` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good idea not to use `^` for installed versions when developing an application to make sure that all developers are using the exact same versions of the packages.

Also make sure that you install packages using `npm ci` and not `npm install` in your Docker container.

I suspect that currently you are doing an `npm install` which installs different (probably newer) packages in the container than locally and this leads to a different result. Doing `npm ci` will solve this issue as it is going to install the exact packages described by your `package-lock.json` file which is hopefully checked into your GIT or whatever versioning tool.

Comment: I am having a similar problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70502813/typography-error-makestyles-stylestheme-styleprops-root
I use yarn

Comment: late reply but just got back at this project and using `npm ci` fixed it :)