# Typography error - makeStyles - 'Styles<Theme, StyleProps, "root"

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I am experiencing the following error on a small React app.

[image: THE ERROR I GET]

I use `"@material-ui/core": "4.11.3"`

I have a `Text.tsx` component and its styles are in `Text.styles.tsx`. I use the `makeStyles` function.

**text.styles.tsx**

```
import { makeStyles, Theme } from '@material-ui/core';

interface StyleProps {
  marginRight: number;
  marginLeft: number;
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => {
  return {
    root: {
      marginRight: (props: StyleProps) => theme.spacing(props.marginRight),
      marginLeft: (props: StyleProps) => theme.spacing(props.marginLeft),
    },
    weightBold: {
      fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightBold,
    },
    weightSemiBold: {
      fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightMedium,
    },
    weightRegular: {
      fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightRegular,
    },
    colorWhite: {
      color: theme.palette.background.default,
    },
    underlinedText: {
      textDecoration: 'underline',
    },
    notUnderlinedText: {
      textDecoration: 'none',
    },
  };
});

export default useStyles;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here, because I use the same stuffs and it works fine. The path where to import is slightly different:

```
import { makeStyles, Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
```

UPDATE: here is an example of code I'm using every day:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Theme, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import IconExpand from "@material-ui/icons/VerticalSplitTwoTone";

import clsx from "clsx";

import { TooltipIconButton } from "../components";
import { langUI } from "../lang";


const useStyles = makeStyles(
    ({ spacing, palette }: Theme) => ({
        root: {
            //
        },
        icon: {
            color: palette.grey[500],
        },
    })
);


export type TSidebarExpButtonProps = {
    readonly className?: string;
    readonly onClick?: () => void;
}

export function SidebarExpButton(props: TSidebarExpButtonProps): JSX.Element {
    const {
        className,
        onClick,
    } = props;

    const classes = useStyles(props);

    return (
        <TooltipIconButton
            className={clsx(classes.root, className)}
            title={langUI.provider.CmdExpand()}
            onClick={onClick}
        >
            <IconExpand
                className={classes.icon}
            />
        </TooltipIconButton>
    )
}
```

Comment: Sadly it does not solve the issue. Can you tell me the version of your material ui?

Comment: 4.11.3 for me, as well